# How to read JSON data from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Snapped code returns data from url in JSON format, how to create function to read data returned by this code in JQuery ?

```
var RealDataApi = function () {
var url_getgatedata = "api/realdata/getgatedata";

return {
    getGateData: function (done, fail, always) {
        var jqxhr = $.get(url_getgatedata);
        jqXhrHandler(jqxhr, done, fail, always);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the headers or parameters in the URL and by using postman you can get the JSON. 
Some of the headers will be encrypted in the URL.